# How to find dependencies for Tabulator

Tags: javascript, angular, tabulator

Is there somewhere I can see the full list of dependencies for Tabulator 4.2. I have tried checking the package.json but all I seem to find are the devDependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Tabulator does not use any dependency. It only uses the devDependencies for builds and tests (gulp, babel, jshint...).